# Animal identification (larva)

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

I found a tiny, white animal in my mouth on the morning of June 28, 2015, in Toronto, Ontario. Luckily I don't seem to have hurt it. I was eating some sunflower and pumpkin seeds at the time. I believe that's how it got there.

The pictures include a toothpick and a Canadian cent to give an idea of its size.

I also took a video of it crawling around. I will post it if the pictures are not sufficient for identification.

[image: Unidentified animal.]

[image: Unidentified animal.]

Comment: Did you see any dots on it?

Comment: @Ilan I don't see any dots on it. It looks very much like the picture you posted. I still have it. I might try to keep it until it molts.

Comment: Oh, is it still alive? So keep it, it would be nice to see the actual moth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This animal is moth [larva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larva). The images presented are blurry, but if there are no any dots on the larva my first suggestion is:

[pantry/Indian meal moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_mealmoth) larvae -

[image]

"They are a common grain-feeding pest found around the world, feeding on cereals and similar products."

([picture source](http://pixshark.com/indian-meal-moth-larvae-webbing.htm))